# How do I interpret an image of a spectrogram of an audio wind signal?

Tags: python, spectrogram

I am running the following code in python to get the spectrogram of a audio signal of wind:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
#  Load the audio as a waveform `y`
#    Store the sampling rate as `sr`
file_path = "wind.wav"
y, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr = None, mono=True, offset = 0.0,  duration=None)
D = librosa.stft(y)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(D,ref=np.max),y_axis='log', x_axis='time')
plt.title('Power spectrogram')
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.tight_layout()
```

I get the following image:

[image]

My question: How do I interpret this image? What exactly am I looking at and what are the frequencies in this audio file?

Comment: Hi! You've figured out it's called a *spectrogram*; at least wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) on that, so could you please base your question off what you've researched so far? really little sense that we copy down an article that is available on the internet!

Comment: Most of your graph is black. Try plotting it with a log frequency axis. A) you get way better frequency resolution where the action is: B) it's much more appropriate for assessing audible features of the noise (as human hearing also uses mostly  log frequency scale).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The almost steady colored part between 1 s and 35 s, and below about 30 Hz may be the sign of a   low-frequency, continuous noise that seems to be common to mild winds. There seems to be occasional gusts of wind around 12 s to 17 s or 22 s to 25 s. However, the needle aspect of the  spectrogram coefficients may suggest to modify the window, and the little information on frequencies above 256/512 Hz would suggest to look closer at the low frequencies, possibly with a linear frequency scale to better see details.

Comment: Awesome weather report, congrats! :)

Comment: Very mild wind conditions! Stay at home, for fear of aerosols :)