# Tell a recording of Martian wind from a recording of Earth's wind

Tags: spectrogram, audio-processing, sound-recognition

[image: MartianWind]

[Perseverance Rover's SuperCam Records Wind on Mars](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25714/perseverance-rovers-supercam-records-wind-on-mars/), sol 11

(Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech/LANL/CNES/CNRS/ISAE-Supaero)

[image: z96Ws]

[How do I interpret an image of a spectrogram of an audio wind signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/how-do-i-interpret-an-image-of-a-spectrogram-of-an-audio-wind-signal)

(Credit: user1068636@dsp.SE)

Looks similar, isn't it?

I see a glimpse of challenge in [question #74103](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/how-do-i-interpret-an-image-of-a-spectrogram-of-an-audio-wind-signal). Even if these are unrelated sound recordings, is it possible, examining only audio, tell a recording of Martian wind from a recording of Earth's wind?

To ward off a prompt redirection to space.SE or elsewhere: what help (if any) DSP can offer to researchers of the Martian atmosphere in analysis of audio recordings, in view of the above?

Comment: It's about to be wind again :)

Comment: Only sort of joking, but if there’s birds and stuff, it’s probably earth wind.

Comment: @DanSzabo What about stereo recording? Does it help, birds and bees notwithstanding?